# Problems with Jquery DatePicker and BootstrapModal on Jquery >= 2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to put datepicker on input inside bootstrap modal.The datepicker it works well inside template except for modals (using JQuery 2+)
However, if I'm using JQuery 1.9 for example, the datepicker works well everywhere.

I tried   [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sudiptabanerjee/93eTU/)

```js
 $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
     minDate: '+5d',
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     altField: "#idTourDateDetailsHidden",
     altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
 });
```

```css
.clsDatePicker {
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="idTourDateDetails">Tour Start Date:</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" name="idTourDateDetails" id="idTourDateDetails" readonly="readonly" class="form-control clsDatePicker"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="calIconTourDateDetails" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>

                            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
```

Here,also when you switch to jQuery 2.0.2 ,that one not works anymore.

I need some help in this way, and I don't want to use previous versions of JQuery.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to include jQuery UI in your fiddle and then it works fine:
[updated fiddle, using jQuery 2.1.0, and jQuery-ui.js](http://jsfiddle.net/93eTU/686/)

```
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js
```

(Essentially, I think you're just missing the necessary jquery-ui.js link)

Comment: It's ok now.I still wonder how that works with JQuery 1.9 without explicitly including Jquery UI.On the other hand I putted this in my bundle config but still no results there...

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox (35.01).

Comment: So to be sure I get you, you're saying the fiddle works, but your code still does not work, even after including jQuery UI?

Comment: That was a simple example and I though that was enough to solve the problem.Here, I still cannot use datepicker inside bootstrap modal.Maybe it is because of some conflicts or so.It's very hard and particulary problem to reproduce it.Lots of javascript here..Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found:

```
$('.datepicker2').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function () { 
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 9999);                   
     }
});
```

It was so simple...Actually the element existed inside, so it triggered well but the z-index was somehow too low